# Replace only one line in an open connection with a longer vector

Tags: r, file, text

I want to replace only ONE line of my text connection in R, but I find that if the replace string is longer it anyway goes into the next line... how can I prevent this?

An example:

Let's say I make a 2-row text file, and open it for reading + writing:

```
write(rbind("This is the first line</a>", "This is the second line"),"test.txt")
fileName <- "test.txt"
FileToChange <- file(fileName, "r+b")
# readLines(FileToChange,1)
```

if you uncomment that last one, you can see that it is in fact 2 lines)

OK, now I read in line 1, and replace it w/ the longer string:

```
FileToChange.line <- readLines(FileToChange,1)
FileToChange.line
newStuff <-"EVIL NEW TEXT"
replacedText <- gsub("</a", paste(" ", newStuff," </a",sep=""), FileToChange.line)
replacedText
```

And here I try to replace JUST the first line:

```
writeLines(replacedText, FileToChange, sep="\n")
close(FileToChange)
```

This will give:

*This is the first line EVIL NEW TEXT*

*cond line*

See how the second line is 'eaten up'? This is because it's simply replacing characters... but it I'm not using `writeChar()`, I'm using 'writeLines()`. I also tried to use`write()` to no avail.

What gives?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The solution was to use an intermediary. Then the steps are:

1. Read entire file and assign to an array
2. Replace first entry of that array
3. Assign corrected array back to the file.

Winning code follows:

```
write(rbind("This is the first line</a>", "This is the second line"),"test.txt")
fileName <- "test.txt"
FileToChange <- file(fileName, "r+b")

a <-  readLines(FileToChange)

FileToChange.line <- a[1]
newStuff <-"EVIL NEW TEXT"
a[1] <- gsub("</a", paste(" ", newStuff," </a",sep=""), a[1])

write(a,fileName)
close(FileToChange)
```